# How to run $("tr").each(function() {} on a webpage given a url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-scraping

I'm trying to get some table data from an external url. Let's say that url is defined by the variable "url." How can I use javascript/jquery to get what I want? I want it to be able to run the code I've written below on that url so I can obtain the data I want and then display that data on a different webpage.

```
`
var arrdata = []
$("tr").each(function(){
    var currentRow = $(this);
    var header_value = currentRow.find("th:eq(0)").text();
    arrdata.push(header_value);
});
`
```

Comment: are you asking how to get the data, like with an ajax call?

Comment: you need all tr in the page or some special requirement ?

Comment: Want to get the table data from external webpage. Am I right?

Comment: You would need to do it from the back end with selenium or puppeteer

Comment: I'm trying to basically figure out how to get data from another url when I am already on a webpage using jquery/js without having to go to said webpage

Comment: I'm trying to stay on one webpage and get data from another webpage to display that data on the webpage I am currently on without having to open up a new browser tab and go to that other webpage to get the data

Answer (score 1):

```
fetch(url)
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(function (content) {
        $(content).find("tr").each(function (index) {
            alert($(this).text()); //do what you need
        })
    })
```

Comment: Using this solution, how do you propose dealing with CORS issues?

Comment: CORS is not an issue of this question. Maybe he/she wants to load data from the same host. Or from host with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *. 
Anyway, the question is "How to run $(“tr”).each(function() {}) on a webpage given a url"

Comment: "I'm trying to get some table data from an **external** url…"

Comment: I'm trying to basically figure out how to get data from another url when I am already on a webpage using jquery/js without having to go to said webpage

Comment: @user3462192 script above didn't help? do you have any errors in console?